# Cron Find & Replace via ssh - send a result via mail

Tags: ssh, email, cron

I'm having a small issue, i'm running and cron task every 5 minutes which is looking text chain and replacing it with nothing.. In order to optmize something i would like to add a new function to my cronstrask : send me an email if it replaces something.. if the crontask does not find the chain no need to send a mail. I have no idea how to do that , maybe you can help me . Here is my current cron task :

```
find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$chain if would like to era$ $g'
```

Comment: Write a script.  Call your script from Cron.

Answer (score 1):

By design, `cron` emails the output of any job to the MAILTO variable, or if that is not set, the owner of the job (e.g. `root`) is email. Call your script from `cron` and set the correct email alias, and you'll get mail if the script produces output.